# Calculate MAX of a RELATEDTABLE

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a `IF` function and would like to calculate the `MAX` of a column from a `RELATEDTABLE` inside the condition. The problem is that `MAXA` needs a column and I can't figure out how to return one column of a `RELATEDTABLE`.

```
= IF(MAXA(RELATEDTABLE(MyTable))
```

I can't simply use `RELATED` because the relationships between my tables don't allow this (one to many relationships).

Comment: You could group your related table by the foreign key with your max aggregation. This way you have a one to one relationship between those two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to find the maximum value of a column in a table on many-side of the relationship (related table) for each row in a table on the one side of the relationship then simple

```
VAR max_val = MAX(MyTable(column_name)) 
.. IF (max_val ...)
```

would suffice (if used in a measure).

If you want to use it in a DAX formula for a calculated column created in a table on the one side of the relationship then `CALCULATE` needs to be used to switch row context into a filter context

```
VAR max_val = CALCULATE ( MAX(MyTable(column_name)) )
.. IF (max_val ... )
```

*Here `Mydateble` is the table that is on many-side of the relationship*